# Calculate a Percentage based off 2 conditions for 2 columns (1 cond per 1 col) in sqlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Given the table format below

```
id  book_name(TEXT) rating(REAL)
1   The Book          50.0
2   Perks Of          30.2
3   book game         100.0 
4   Hobbit            80.0
```

I want to calculate a percentage of book_name that contain "book" in the text (not case sensitive) and has a rating above 50.0. The percentage would be calculated as (# of rows that meet 2 conditions / # of total rows). The answer in this case is calculated by 2/4 = **50.0** (this is in percentage form)

I'd want to return 50.0 as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a CASE statement inside SUM() to do your conditional count -

```sql
SELECT ROUND((SUM(CASE WHEN book_name LIKE '%book%' AND rating >= 50 THEN 1 END)/COUNT(*)) * 100, 1)
FROM books
```

*UPDATE*

I added another pair of parentheses around the division of the two COUNTs to address the issue mentioned by @ChrisCharley in the comments below.

Comment: If I want this in sqlite, what is the alternative for if()? I tried it and if doesn't exist in sqlite

Comment: I have modified my answer to use CASE. Sorry, I didn't realise this was for sqlite.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am very new to sql in general so, I was wondering how I can see the value of that query within Python using sqlite library.

Comment: I suggest you post a new question with the Python code you have tried so far. Good luck!

Comment: Note that I had to change the order of items in the SELECT stmt. `SELECT ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN name LIKE '%book%' AND rating >= 50 THEN 1 END)*100/COUNT(*), 1)` When I used your order, I got a result of '0'. With the items changed, I got the answer '50'.

Comment: Although adding _another pair of parentheses around the division of the two COUNTs_ didn't give the answer, changing the `1` in SUM to `1.0` did  (`AND rating >= 50 THEN 1.0 END`)

Comment: @nnichols By the way, very nice solution.  I doubt I could have gotten it  `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use lower then filter using regex on conditions

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"id":[1,2,3,4], "book_name(TEXT)":["The Book","Perks Of","book game","Hobbit"],"rating(REAL)":[50.0,30.2,100.0, 80.0] }
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data["lower"] = data["book_name(TEXT)"].str.lower()
data1 = data[data.lower.str.contains("book")==True]
data1 = data1[data1["rating(REAL)"]>=50.0]
(len(data1)/len(data))*100
```

Comment: I need this in a SQL query unfortunately. But this would work in python, thank you!